# LibGDX - Render texture background twisted

Tags: java, libgdx, terrain-rendering

I am developing a 2D survival game. In these days, without make some features, I am fixing some bug. There is one which I got stuck on: my map has a background made with grass, earth, desert, water and dungeon texture. Above them blocks are rendered. My problem is that block's texture is
rendered a bit twisted. I cannot understand if the background is rendered wrongly or block's.

p.s. My block aren't a simple 2D texture, this is due to at the beginning: I wanted to make a 2D game with a perspective camera in order to seems it like Factorium; but later I changed idea. Now I keep using blocks as 3D model made up with Blockbench. I've model them in order to use only positive cords (blockbench makes axises begin from center-down of block, so I tried to move translate of 8,8)

[image]
As you can see, every block has an offset increased on the left.

[image]
As you can see, I translated of 8, 8

Player with camera class:

```
public abstract class Player3D extends DynamicEntity {

private StackItem mouseStack = StackItem.EMPTY;

private OrthographicCamera camera;
public PlayerHud playerHud;
public boolean inventoryOpen;
public PlayerInventory inventory;   //Player inventory
float radians;
int viewportH, viewportW;

public Player3D(int x, int y) {
    super("player/player.obj");
    this.setPosition(new Vector3(x, y, 0));
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(0.9f);
    this.setPhysic(shape, BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody, new FixtureDef());
    this.playerHud = new PlayerHud();
}

/**
 * Set camera about the player
 */
public void setCamera(WorldSize worldSize){
    this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/32, Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/32);
    this.camera.position.set(this.getPlayerPos());
    this.camera.position.add(0f, 0f, 1f);
    this.camera.lookAt(this.getPosition());
    this.camera.update();

    this.viewportW = (int)this.camera.viewportWidth/2;
    this.viewportH = (int)this.camera.viewportHeight/2;
    this.moveCamera(worldSize.getWidth(), worldSize.getHeight());
}

/**
 * Called by render(), it provides listener on WASD in order to
 * move player, notice that camera is constraints to that, but won't when map edge has been got
 */
public void move(FlatWorld flatWorld, int worldWidth, int worldHeight) {

    int x = 0, y = 0;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W))
        y = 1;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))
        y = -1;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A))
        x = -1;
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))
        x = 1;

    if(x != 0 || y != 0) {
        if (this.canPlayerMove(flatWorld, new Vector3(x, y, 0), worldWidth, worldHeight)) {
            this.modelInstance.transform.translate(x, y, 0);
            this.moveCamera(worldWidth, worldHeight);
        }
    }
    this.renderModel(null);
}

/**
 * Called in order to move camera within screen size. If player is almost to the edge,
 * camera will stop following it
 * @param worldWidth
 * @param worldHeight
 */
public void moveCamera(int worldWidth, int worldHeight){
        float newCameraX = Math.min(Math.max(this.getPlayerX(), this.viewportW), worldWidth - this.viewportW);
        float newCameraY = Math.min(Math.max(this.getPlayerY(), this.viewportH), worldHeight - this.viewportH);
        this.camera.position.set(newCameraX, newCameraY, this.camera.position.z);
        this.camera.update();
}

/**
 * Get a copy of the current position of the player, translate as the future one;
 *
 * @param translateCords how much player has to be moved
 * @return if the player can me moved<br> e.g. if the camera will not be over the map's edge
 * after have been moved
 */
private boolean canPlayerMove(FlatWorld flatWorld, Vector3 translateCords, int worldWidth, int worldHeight) {
    Vector3 playerPos = this.modelInstance.copy().transform.translate(translateCords).getTranslation(new Vector3());
    int xPlayer = (int)playerPos.x;
    int yPlayer = (int)playerPos.y;
    //Checking future player pos
    if(playerPos.x > 0 && playerPos.x < worldWidth && playerPos.y > 0 && playerPos.y < worldHeight){
        Block block = flatWorld.getBlocks().getBlockAt((int)playerPos.x, (int)playerPos.y);
        if(block != null)
            return block.getTypeBlock() == TypeBlock.WALKTHROUGH;
        return  flatWorld.getBlocksCourt().getCourt()[yPlayer][xPlayer] != FlatBlock.WATER;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Called when mouse is moved, in order to rotate player towards pointer<br>
 * Mouse pointer cords begins from top-left corner. In order to make it relative
 * to the centre of the window, it is got via Camera#unproject
 */
public boolean rotatePlayerToMouse() {
    //get mouse pos relative to the centre of screen
    Vector3 mousePos = this.camera.unproject(new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0));
    Vector3 playerPos = this.getPosition();
    radians = (float) Math.atan2(mousePos.y - playerPos.y, mousePos.x - playerPos.x);
    radians -= Math.PI / 2; //It is relative to X-axis, but I need it relative to Y one
    this.modelInstance.transform.setFromEulerAnglesRad(0, 0, radians).setTranslation(playerPos);
    return true;
}


/**
 * Player owns camera, so when it is rendered, null will be passed as camera
 * @param camera
 */
@Override
public void renderModel(Camera camera) {
    super.renderModel(this.camera);
}

public Vector3 getPlayerPos(){ return this.getPosition();}
public int getPlayerX(){ return (int)getPlayerPos().x;}
public int getPlayerY(){ return (int)getPlayerPos().y;}

public OrthographicCamera getCamera(){ return camera; }

public StackItem getMouseStack() {
    return mouseStack;
}

public float getRadians() {
    return radians;
}

public void setMouseStack(StackItem mouseStack) {
    this.mouseStack = mouseStack;
}
```

}

Render background class:

```
    int scale = 32;
    public void renderWorld(Camera camera) {
    int startX = (int) (camera.position.x - camera.viewportWidth/2);
    int startY = (int) (camera.position.y - camera.viewportHeight/2);
    int width = (int) (camera.position.x + camera.viewportWidth/2);
    int height = (int) (camera.position.y + camera.viewportHeight/2);

    this.spriteBatch.begin();
    for (int x = startX; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = startY; y < height; y++) {
            this.spriteBatch.draw(this.court[y][x], (x - startX) * scale, (y - startY) * scale, scale, scale);
        }
    }
    this.spriteBatch.end();
}
```

In order to render model block I use Model, ModelInstance and ModelBatch

Comment: I don't see a "twist" here, just a difference in scale or spacing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Google translate...